# Get dynamic substring in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string like this:

> D:\ClickSitePlayer\ClickSitePlayer\ClickSitePlayer\bin\Debug\sad_3.mp4

At the end of the string there is a file name (video name). the file name is not fixed and will change each time.

1 - How can i get file name (sad_3.mp4) in this string?

2 - After getting file name, how can i get file id? (file id comes after '_' and is 3 here)

Comment: search split on internet

Comment: @vivek nuna thanks. I had not seen this topic.

Comment: Thanks for accepting it as answer. But I'm gonna delete it anyways. You'll get use to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Path.GetFileName (MyPath)`
2. You want to probably use Regex to get a good match and extract the number.

Stackoverflow already has numerous similar questions and very good answers.

I encourage youe to expand ur search before asking.

Comment: Or just use split on the underscore...